# transform: rotate3d() Safari (iOS) issues

Tags: html, css, safari

I am seeing that there are errors in Safari iOS version with the `transform: rotate3d()`

I am doing the test with this HTML code

```
<span class="safari-box"></span>
```

For example, if I do the following I can see the animation

```
/* test */
.safari-box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: $color-principal;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    border-radius: 20px;
    animation: safari-box-animation 2s infinite;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@keyframes safari-box-animation {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate3d(1,.5,1, 180deg);
        transform: rotate3d(1,.5,1, 180deg);
    }
}
```

But if I increase the animation degrees it stops working

```
/* test */
.safari-box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: $color-principal;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    border-radius: 20px;
    animation: safari-box-animation 2s infinite;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@keyframes safari-box-animation {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate3d(1,.5,1, 1080deg);
        transform: rotate3d(1,.5,1, 1080deg);
    }
}
```

Anyone know what might be happening?

Answer (score 0):

After looking around I noticed that you require an intermediate keyframe for 50%, in this case I just halfed the 100% value for 50%.

```css
.safari-box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: red;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    border-radius: 20px;
    animation: safari-box-animation 2s infinite;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@keyframes safari-box-animation {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    50% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate3d(1,.5,1, 540deg);
        transform: rotate3d(1,.5,1, 540deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate3d(1,.5,1, 1080deg);
        transform: rotate3d(1,.5,1, 1080deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<span class="safari-box"></span>
```

[Video of it working on Safari PC.](https://youtu.be/ai4qS5TP-zk)

[Video of it working on Safari iPhone 11 Pro](https://youtube.com/shorts/u001O6Sibh4?feature=share)

This is the test case on my webserver so you can test it easily on your Apple phone.

https://refuzion.nl/uploads/test.html

If this is not what you meant with your question, let me know, and I might be able to help you further.

Comment: just now realized you are talking about iOS. I will upload the test to my server and see if it works.

Comment: Yess!! but If you notice, the animation of the video in Safari PC is different from the iOS version

Comment: Yes I think that the mobile IOS has a max speed for the animations to prevent overloading the browsers resources I am not sure about this however.

Comment: I also thought that it could be some kind of restriction for the mobile version, but I asked to verify that it was not just me who was experiencing it. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: no problem! good luck with your project